# ERROR: In MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing

Tags: android, android-support-library

R файл генерируется с ошибкой.

Код ошибки в библиотеке:

```
android-support-v7-appcompat] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
```

Путем ручного перебора всех xml файлов я нашла что в этом коде ошибка, но как исправить:

```
<declare-styleable name="MenuView">
        <!-- Default appearance of menu item text. -->
        <attr name="android:itemTextAppearance"/>
        <!-- Default horizontal divider between rows of menu items. -->
        <attr name="android:horizontalDivider"/>
        <!-- Default vertical divider between menu items. -->
        <attr name="android:verticalDivider"/>
        <!-- Default background for the menu header. -->
        <attr name="android:headerBackground"/>
        <!-- Default background for each menu item. -->
        <attr name="android:itemBackground"/>
        <!-- Default animations for the menu. -->
        <attr name="android:windowAnimationStyle"/>
        <!-- Default disabled icon alpha for each menu item that shows an icon. -->
        <attr name="android:itemIconDisabledAlpha"/>
        <!-- Whether space should be reserved in layout when an icon is missing. -->
        <attr name="android:preserveIconSpacing"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

В логах, больше ошибок нет.

Comment: И чистила, и пересобирала. Даже обновила support. Все та же ошибка.

Comment: пересобирала, удаляла, заново добавляла - все в пустую...

Comment: <attr name="android:preserveIconSpacing"/>   удали эту строчку

Comment: Как вариант убрать везде android:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets) Прав. Я удалила эту строчку и библиотека заработала. Я с самого начала пыталась вылечить, а не удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю что исправлять код библиотеки в данном случае неверное решение, т.к. это внешний код и эти изменения в либу не попадут. Скорее всего версия библиотеки ниже чем targetSdkVersion приложения, это надо поправить.